# jquery ajax post stops when called

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I am new to web Development and I am developing a jsp web application for my college. I want to use ajax to do insert, update and delete operations in the table. But when the execution reaches to ajax script, the execution just freezes and no result is displayed. Below is my code:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="org.h2.tools.Server"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="org.h2.Driver"%>

<link href="BSTemplate/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="Styles/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="BSTemplate/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/JQuery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function post_(){    
    $.post("newjsp.ajax.jsp",
    {
      username: document.getElementById("username").value,
      password: document.getElementById("password").value
    },
    function(data,status){
        if(data.trim() ==="success")
            window.location="Home.jsp";
        else
            alert("Data: " + data.trim() + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="login">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="login-row" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <center><img src="Img/Image1.png" alt="Image Cannot Be Displayed"/></center>
            <div id="login-column" class="col-md-6">
                <div id="login-box"  class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="login-form" class="form">
                        <h3 class="text-center text-info">Member Login</h3>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username" class="text-info">Username:</label><br>
                            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="User Name" tabindex="1" class="form-control" required="true" autofocus>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="text-info">Password:</label><br>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password"  required="true" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="post_()" tabindex="3" class="btn btn-info btn-md" style="width:100px" value="Login">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: post_ is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick (newjsp.jsp:50). This is the error message I gotRory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="BSTemplate/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="Styles/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="BSTemplate/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/JQuery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function post_(){  

    $.post("newjsp.ajax.jsp",
    {
      username: document.getElementById("username").value,
      password: document.getElementById("password").value
    },
    function(data,status){
    alert(status);
        if(data.trim() ==="success")
            window.location="Home.jsp";
        else
            alert("Data: " + data.trim() + "\nStatus: " + status);
    }).fail(function(msg) {
    alert( "error"+JSON.stringify(msg) );
  });
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="login">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="login-row" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <center><img src="Img/Image1.png" alt="Image Cannot Be Displayed"/></center>
            <div id="login-column" class="col-md-6">
                <div id="login-box"  class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="login-form" class="form">
                        <h3 class="text-center text-info">Member Login</h3>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username" class="text-info">Username:</label><br>
                            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="User Name" tabindex="1" class="form-control" required="true" autofocus>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="text-info">Password:</label><br>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password"  required="true" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="post_()" tabindex="3" class="btn btn-info btn-md" style="width:100px" value="Login">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

This works.
Please check your jquery library loading correctly.

Comment: The project runs on localhost and will not have internet facility. Will it work if I download the jquery file and use it offline?

Comment: Of course it will work. Add the jquery file in the classpath

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Sumesh. I have made some mistakes in the sql query. The Json error Popup Message helped me solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Load js in correct order,

you need to load Jquery library first, and then anything else
because other library or js code will work only if jquery is loaded,

```
<script src="Scripts/JQuery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="BSTemplate/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

PS: first you should always check error messages you get

Comment: I did as you said but I get this error message in the console.log().  Uncaught ReferenceError: post_ is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick (newjsp.jsp:50).

Comment: move your js  code at the bottom, i would preffer a better name, as you said you are new so i would advise you to do naming properly,